# Is it possible to prefer later matches using conditional regex?

Tags: regex

Suppose one would like to match an arbitrary number, that is either preceded or followed by a certain string. However, if possible, the pattern should always prefer to match the substring where the number is followed by the string.

For example:

1. the string `1234 foo` should match.
2. the string `foo 1234` should match.
3. the string `1234 foo 1234` should produce the match `1234 foo`.
4. (most important) the string `foo 1234 foo` should produce the match `1234 foo` and not `foo 1234`.

To avoid having the same expression twice, only inverted and separated by an or, I've been trying to implement it using a conditional pattern. Using the pattern below works for the cases 1-3, but fails for case 4 as it matches `foo 1234`.

```
(\d+)?(?:(?(1) ?)(foo) ??)(?(1)|(?:(\d+)))
```

Adding a negative lookahead to the conditional like below also doesn't help. The string `foo 1234 foo` now produces the two matches `foo 123` and `4 foo`.

```
(\d+)?(?:(?(1) ?)(foo) ??)(?(1)|(?:(\d+)(?! ?foo)))
```

Since the regex is greedy it always matches the non-preferred substring in case 4 first. Is there a way to make the regex expression prefer the later match with a conditional expression?

Comment: Why not just something as simple as `foo \d+|\d+ foo(?! \d+)`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/XR8e0Y/1

Comment: @41686d6564 that literally does not work for the 4th point (marked most important) though. https://regex101.com/r/XR8e0Y/2

Comment: That solution was meant by "To avoid having the same expression twice, only inverted and separated by an or". The reason is that in my specific case the foo string is already a complex regular expression with multiple named capture groups. I would like to avoid having to duplicate every named capture group.

Comment: @Chase I made a mistake while copying the sample inputs. It should've been the other way around: `\d+ foo|foo 1234(?! foo)`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zSPXog/1

Comment: @Ferdinand Your second attempt does have `foo` twice though.

Comment: @41686d6564, yes that was just to illustrate that a negative lookahead in the second condtional will not work. On top of that, because it's a negative lookahead, the capture groups would not appear in the match and therefore do not need to be doubled. Your last example also doesn't work because it specifically searches for the string 1234 and not any arbitrary number. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: @Ferdinand Well, that was another typo (I should've had my coffee before commenting :-D), but you probably figured that I meant `\d+` instead of `1234`. Anyway, check my answer below. I believe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if you don't want to reuse `foo` unless it's in a Lookahead, I believe the following pattern would meet all your conditions:

```
(\d+)?(?(1) )(foo)(?(1)| (\d+)\b(?! foo))
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9wmIUf/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```
(\d+)?          # An optional capturing group matching one or more digits.
(?(1) )         # If the previous group exists, match a space character.
(foo)           # A second capturing group to capture "foo".
(?              # If...
    (1)         # ..the first group exists, match nothing.
|               # Else...
    [ ]         # Match a space character.
    (\d+)       # A third capturing group matching one or more digits.
    \b          # Assert a word boundary to make sure no more digits following.
    (?! foo)    # A negative Lookahead to make sure " foo" is not following.
)               # End If.
```

An alternative approach for that last part if the digits don't have to end with a word boundary would be to get rid of `\b` and add `\d*` in the negative Lookahead:

```
(\d+)?(?(1) )(foo)(?(1)| (\d+)(?!\d* foo))
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LH0mZD/1)**.

---

Another solution is to wrap the third digit capturing group in an atomic group, to prevent backtracking in the following negative lookahead. This solves an issue for the first solution, such that there doesn't have to be a word boundary between the numerical substring and foo. It also solves an issue with the second solution, such that it allows for the numerical substring to be more complex (like including decimals `\d+.?\d*`).

<sup>(Credits go to the OP, [Ferdinand Schlatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8421222/ferdinand-schlatt))</sup>

```
(\d+)?(?(1) )(foo)(?(1)| (?>(\d+))(?! foo))
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LH0mZD/2)**

Comment: I just found another solution which works better in my particular case. Instead of consuming all digits or checking for a word boundary in the negative lookahead, wrap the third capturing group for digits in an atomic to disallow backtracking: https://regex101.com/r/LH0mZD/2. Mind adding the solution?

Comment: @Ferdinand Using an atomic group seems like a good alternative too. You may post it as a separate answer if you wish (yes, you can answer your own question), or if you don't want to, I could (or you, feel free to) edit it into my answer.

Comment: I added it to your answer to avoid clutter. All solutions are in one place then :) Thanks for your help!